# Asp Dotnet 6 - Angular: Storing login data problem

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2

i am having a problem when using session with Asp backend and Angular frontend to store login data when login from angular:

Here is my controller, the login param is just simply email and password:

```
        [HttpPost("login")]
        [Consumes("application/json")]
        [Produces("application/json")]
        public IActionResult Login([FromBody] Login login)
        {
            try
            {
                if (_accountService.Login(login))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("=========BEFORE: " + HttpContext.Session.GetString("id"));

                    var account = _accountService.FindByEmailController(login.Email);
                    HttpContext.Session.SetString("id", account.Id.ToString());
                    HttpContext.Session.SetString("departmentId", account.DepartmentId.ToString());

                    Console.WriteLine("=========AFTER: " + HttpContext.Session.GetString("id"));
                    return Ok(new
                    {
                        Result = true
                    });
                }
                return BadRequest();
            }
            catch
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
```

And in angular, i got a button which named "login" will call this Login Api:

```
  login(){
    let login: Login = {
      email: 'superadmin@gmail.com',
      password: '123'
    }
    this.accountService.login(login).then(
      res => {
        this.result = res
        this.loginStatus = this.result.result as boolean
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    )
  }
```

Here is the angular login service:

```
async login(login: Login){
    return await lastValueFrom(this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:5222/api/account/login', login));
}
```

Here is my program file:

```
using CallCenter.Models;
using CallCenter.Services;
using CallCenter.ServicesImpl;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
});
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(option => option.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlServer("connectionString"));

builder.Services.AddScoped<IAccountService, AccountServiceImpl>()

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseSession();

app.UseCors(builder => builder
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
                    .AllowCredentials()
                );

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

And this is what i got, after the first click:

- The `Console.WriteLine("=========BEFORE: " + HttpContext.Session.GetString("id"));` will not print "id" session because it got none.
- And `Console.WriteLine("=========AFTER: " + HttpContext.Session.GetString("id"));` will print it because the "id" session already got the value.
- BUT, the moment i hit the button second time, the result is still the same, because i expect `Console.WriteLine("=========BEFORE: " + HttpContext.Session.GetString("id"));` will print the value out, cause it already got value from the first click, but "id" session doesnt got the value, picture below is the result.

[image]

I am kinda clueless of how to store data from angular side now, since session never work at all, please help :(

Comment: Please be clear about whether you're using ASP, ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core. These are all different things, do not mix and match them.

Comment: On to your question, how is the session being persisted? Are you using session cookies, etc.? Does your angular frontend include the session info in the requests?

Comment: @phuzi im only using "builder.Services.AddSession" and "app.UseSession()" on asp.net side, other than that, i dont really know

Comment: By default, I believe that ASP.NET Core uses Cookies. Can you see any cookies being transferred with you login requests something like `ASP.NET_SessionId`. Check your browser's dev tools to see if there is a cookie like this also being set.

Comment: @phuzi there is none like that, i just save my session on my .net side, and not sending any beside Ok()

Comment: Not even ".AspNetCore.Session"! There could be a number of reasons the cookie isn't being set. Are you running the site over HTTPS?